# Special characters in R language

Tags: r

I have a table, which looks like this:

```
1β              2β     
1.0199e-01        2.2545e-01       
2.5303e-01        6.5301e-01
1.2151e+00        1.1490e+00
```

and so on...

I want to make a boxplot of this data. The commands I am using is this:

```
pdf('rtest.pdf')
 w1<-read.table("data_CMR",header=T)
 w2<-read.table("data_C",header=T)
boxplot(w1[,], w2[,], w3[,],outline=FALSE,names=c(colnames(w1),colnames(w2),colnames(w3)))
dev.off()
```

The problem is instead of symbol beta (β), I get two dots (..) in the output.

Any suggestions, to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Adding `check.names=FALSE` to your `read.table` commands might help

Comment: @James: Why not as an answer?

Comment: @DWin I can't reproduce the behaviour so not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also works

```
pdf('rtest.pdf')
w1<-read.table("data_CMR",header=T) 
w2<-read.table("data_C",header=T) 
one<-expression(paste("1", beta,sep="")) 
two <- expression(paste("2", beta,sep="")) 
boxplot(w1[,], w2[,], w3[,],outline=FALSE, names=c(one,two)) 
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion to use check.names will prevent the appending of "X" to the "1β" and "2β" which would otherwise occur even once the encoding is sorted out (since column names are not supposed to start with numbers. (One could also have just used the"names" argument to boxplot.)

```
w1<-read.table(text="1β              2β     
 1.0199e-01        2.2545e-01       
 2.5303e-01        6.5301e-01
 1.2151e+00        1.1490e+00",header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8")
boxplot(w1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be an encoding problem. Try adding `encoding='UTF-8'` to your `read.table` statements.

```
w1<-read.table("data_CMR",header=T,encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: I tried fileEncodings also as "ASCII", "UCS-2LE", and "latin1" and could not replicate the reported behavior reported with any of them, but then I'm on a Mac/Unix machine.